# Reading only Integers from a text file and store it in an array

Tags: java

Reading only Integers from a text file and storing in an array and display it to user

How can i read only integers from a text file that contains both Integers ans Strings..

Suppose i have a text file like this..

```
10 10 100 100 Line
10 20 15 30 Rectangle
100 50 50 Circle
10 10 50 50 Line
0 0 0 xyz
```

We should search each token and if we find some meaningful letter Line,Rectangle,Circle
the integers information of that particular Shape should be stored in an array how is this possible..

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (new File ("a.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    if (s.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is an int
        System.out.print(s.nextInt()); // display the found integer
    } else {
        s.next(); // else read the next token
    }
}
```

Comment: `replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","")` `trim()` and `split(" ")`

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

This will only read the integers on lines that contains the String "Line", "Circle" or "Rectangle".

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("sample.txt")).useDelimiter("\\n");
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String line = s.next();
        if(line.matches("^.+(Line|Circle|Rectangle)$")) {
            line = line.replaceAll("(Line|Circle|Rectangle)","");
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            for(String t: tokens) {
                System.out.print(t+" ");
            }
        }
    }
```

The above prints out:
10 10 100 100 10 20 15 30 100 50 50 10 10 50 50

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way is using [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) 
and define your lexer and parser rules.

Otherwise:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = string.split(" "); // this splits the line by spaces
    // ... it is trivial what you should do next
    //
}
```

you can iterate over the tokens of each line
use integer.parseInt(parts[i]) to parse to an Int and catch the exception for a String. This is not very elegant though.

You can use regex instead to match instead.

Comment: A bit overkill for something like this, though

Comment: @KepaniHaole you are right 100% I updated my answer.